# How to encrypt a column in Postgres using Hibernate @ColumnTransformer

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, encryption, orm

I am trying to encrypt a column in my prostrgres DB. The column name is "test" of type "bytea".

My enity code is below,

```
@ColumnTransformer(
          forColumn="test", 
          read="pgp_sym_encrypt(test::bytea, 'mySecretKey')", 
          write="pgp_sym_decrypt(?, 'mySecretKey')")
private String test;
```

When I tried to retrieve the entity, I am getting the encrypted data like below. How do I get the decrypted value programmatically? But I get the actual value If i execute a postgres select query.

```
  "test": "\\xc30d04070302474627ea0994ea657bd24401aaa5543862d57524a407e5dbe2ee0f6f0f33ea4f4474f5bc801dca5d32956d41a975505b12ac000f124177bdc2f4507cbfd724d716aaa513ba46f004dfefd3b2b32eb6"
```

2. When I am trying to persist the entity, I am getting the below error.

> ERROR: column "test" is of type bytea but expression is of type
>   character varying

Comment: I think you placed your function calls inversely. You should use something like `read="pgp_sym_decrypt(test, '<key>')", write="pgp_sym_encrypt(?, '<key>')"`. (Because it is encrypted in the DB & you want decrypted in your application).

Comment: But I'm not sure if that's the right place to embed your key anyway.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use `pgp_sym_encrypt` for write and `pgp_sym_decrypt` for read. You did the opposite.

```
@ColumnTransformer(
    read =  "pgp_sym_decrypt(" +
            "    test, " +
            "    current_setting('encrypt.key')" +
            ")",
    write = "pgp_sym_encrypt( " +
            "    ?, " +
            "    current_setting('encrypt.key')" +
            ") "
)
@Column(columnDefinition = "bytea")
private String test;
```

Because hard-coding the encryption key in the mapping does not sound like a very good idea, we will use the PostgreSQL support for user-defined settings instead.

So, the [`encrypt.key`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-hibernate/) is stored in the `postgresql.conf`configuration file:

```
encrypt.key = 'Wow! So much security.'
```

The [example is on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/tree/49d6c710f58949636d6cf656b13a88c796552f08/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/mapping/encrypt) and works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Same issue after the change. And also I am wondering, why I don't get the decrypted data via my rest API.

Comment: works like a charm..the database field should be of type bytea

Comment: instead of hardcoding the symmetric key in the code it can be read from postgresql.conf properties file with entry encrypt.key = 'mySecretKey'

Comment: That is good and all but is there a way to tell Hibernate to read the 'mySecretKey' from application.properties? We have the use case to store the key in the web app instead of postgres

Comment: How would you do that with a custom Hibernate Type ?

Comment: Asking once again, can anyone provide an example for using encryption key from application.properties ?

Comment: I am using your solution but I still get the result of `\\xc30d04.....`. When I go to the database and execute `select pgp_sym_decrypt((select value from mytable where id = 1), 'my-secret');`, I get the expected result.

Comment: @VladMihalcea What about if postgresql.conf is not accessible? for example like services in Heroku? what is the solution for this?

Comment: You can use session variables for that. Check out this article for more details: https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-audit-logging-triggers/

Comment: @VladMihalcea I am using in production `@ColumnTransformer` in kubernetes pod its working fine, but on develop I am using heroku

Comment: @VladMihalcea so for my case I need something that will be dynamic by checking current spring boot active profile to change the key

Comment: @0x01Brain I have posted an example doing it in the session here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52077348/is-it-possible-to-variabilize-the-password-in-hibernate-columntransformer-for-p/73815778#73815778

Comment: @mdzh See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73815778/767434